# html format text field as phone number

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an `<input>` field that is generated via jQuery(just a call to backend which is returning HTML and updating current page without reload), and I need to show proper formatted phone numbers (pure integers). For example, an integer 1234123235 should be formatted as +1 (234) 123-235

I tried:

```
<input type='tel' pattern='[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}' title='Phone Number (Format: +99(99)9999-9999)' value="12312312123">
```

But it doesn't work. How can I format this field as telephone number?

Comment: your question is not clear and too broad. Please edit your question and try to include some more information about your work so someone can help you. Everyone here is going to downvote you now.. you should be really careful how to ask here. :/

Answer (score 6):

You mean **`1215551000`** format as **`121-555-1000`** .if yes you can use `substr`

```
var PNO = '1215551000',
formatted = PNO .substr(0, 3) + '-' + PNO .substr(3, 3) + '-' + PNO .substr(6,4)
```

Output : **`121-555-1000`**

**Edited:**

```
<p class="phone">1234123235</p>

$(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
    text = text.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "+$1 ($2)-$3-$4");
    return text;
});
```

Output: **`+1 (234)-123-235`**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/4096/)

Comment: and how to use it ? I have jquery that is creating input field. i need format this field

Comment: I have jQuery which updates text field value, and this field should be formatted. Maybe i need call .change and then this function ?